# i need to extract this json format content using php and need to store into db

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to extract these below content using php. Then need to store as seprate fields. Every fields need to split.

```
    [data: {
    date: 2015-08-12
}{
    day: Wed,
    {
        TableName: title1,
        {
            Timing: 2-6,
            Function_name: test
        },
        {
            Timing: 4-8,
            Function_name: demo
        }
    },
    {
        TableName: variable,
        {
            Timing: 3-8,
            Function_name: dest
        }
    },
    {
        TableName: dfdf,
        {
            Timing: 3-7,
            Function_name: gdfgdfg
        }
    }
}]
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? We're here to help, but not to do your work.

Comment: i have try using php explode and split but its not working

Comment: `explode()` and `split()` are not appropriate for parsing JSON. Have you searched for PHP's JSON functions?

Comment: is above is correct json format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function as you are passing json string and it will give you normal php array. And i don't think your posted json string is correct try validating it over [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), it converts a JSON string into a PHP variable.
There's no need to string manipulation in this case.

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r(json_decode($_POST['all_val']));  But it not display anything